# css3 forcus not work in chrome browser or or something wrong?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I going to use this sample on my new design for website http://www.xaluan.com at mobile version
this is: http://www.cssportal.com/css3-preview/demo/css-menu-ex4.html

but this hide effect not work on chrome browser.. 
anyone can help?
thanks a ton
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution works only in Firefox as far as I checked (doesn't work in chrome, opera, ie, safari). To do such things it's much more preffered to use jquery or other javascript libraries.